# How to equate dates to one day of the month

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an Oracle dataset that looks like this:

[image]

Data for several months, i.e. for each month several entries with different days. How can I convert a date according to the following logic: "if the data is for a certain month, equate all dates to some date of this month, for example, to the tenth day"?

Answer (score 0):

Use [TRUNC](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/TRUNC-date.html#GUID-BC82227A-2698-4EC8-8C1A-ABECC64B0E79) which truncates the date column:

```
select trunc(response_dttm, 'MONTH'), othercolumn from yourtable
```

Then all dates in the same month will get the same truncated date.